# Vue router duplicates route on keypress

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have a login button that would navigate to the route `dashboard/` when a login is successful. The button works on click but when I press the enter key it duplicates the route.

So the flow is this:

- Land on login page
- Press the 'Enter' key
- Get to 'Dashboard'
- Click the browser back button
- Press the 'Enter' key

At which point the address becomes `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/dashboard/` instead of just `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/`. What's even more weird is that if I follow the same flow as above but I click the button instead. It works as expected no matter how many times I press the back button. The stripped component is shown below.

```
<template >
  <v-container>
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-col cols='6' align="center">
        <v-form>
          <h1 class="pb-4">Login</h1>

          <v-text-field
            label="Email"
            placeholder="someone@example.com"    
          >
          </v-text-field>
          <v-text-field
            label="Password"
            type="password"
          >
          </v-text-field>

          <v-btn dark block @click="login"> Login </v-btn>
          <br />
          <a href="">Forgot your password?</a>
        </v-form>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showPassword: false,
    };
  },
  mounted(){
    document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
      if (event.key ==='Enter') {
        this.login();
      }
    });
  },
  methods: {
    async login() {
      try {
        //throw 'Login is not setup'
        //do login logic 
        this.$router.push({ path: "dashboard/" });
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is the way you have an event set up with an event listener, which you technically shouldn't need since the native and normal behavior for a form is to submit on enter. Instead of having a click event on your button, use a button type of submit and a prevent default behavior on the form to catch the normal form submission and instead run your submit function. This should then work the same for clicking the button or hitting enter.

Template:

```html
<form @submit.prevent="login()">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    login() {
      // stuff you want to do
    },
  }
```

Vuetify should have ways to set it's properties up to do the same as vanilla forms. But the idea should work the same.

Comment: That works! except the new url becomes `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/?` which would  still navigate to the proper page, but still

Comment: Fun. Maybe there is some kind of code somewhere that thinks it should be adding some kind of params to your URL. Perhaps look into your routing setup to debug that bit.

Comment: Or, one never knows, maybe Vuetify (if that's what you are using there) has something they are sneeking in that you need to turn off with some kind of prop. The blessings and curses of packages and platforms, I suppose.

Comment: Apologies, it works flawlessly. I had forgotten to remove the `@click` handler from the button

Comment: Good deal! Glad I could help. :)